# Convnet regression approach

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, linear-regression, convolution

I want to train a model that predicts a percentage value (0.0-100.0) based on an input image. The exact decimal of the value is not super important, it's more important that it falls within close approximate (+- 2%) of the desired value, although the closer it gets the better.

My approach has been to take an existing convolutional image classifier, and simple change the last layer from 10 classes to one. I used the following model as the base model, and made changes to that one.
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py

Though for some reason I am not able to get the model to learn anything. I tend to get predictions ranging from -+1e7, far from the 0-100 I am looking for.

Some things I am wondering:

- Is there a better way to approach this? (While still utilizing deep learning)
- Is there some way to "help" the model by indicating that the expected output must fall in the range 0-100?
- Am I making some silly mistakes?

I am noticing that my weights and biases barely change at all when training,but I am unable to figure out why.

Would greatly appreciate any help I could get. I have been battling this for some weeks now with very little progress.

This is the code I am using:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
  key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)

  split_res = tf.string_split([key],'_')
  key2 = split_res.values[4]
  example = tf.image.decode_jpeg(record_string)
  processed_example = resize_img(example)
  processed_example2 = reshape_img(processed_example)
  return processed_example2, key2

def resize_img(imgg):
  return tf.image.resize_images(imgg,[128,256])

def reshape_img(imgg):
  return tf.reshape(imgg,shape=[128,256,3])


def input_pipeline( num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
      tf.train.match_filenames_once("./max100/*.jpg"), num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
  min_after_dequeue = 10
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * 3

  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=20, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return  example_batch, label_batch

imb_batch1,label_batch1 = input_pipeline()


# Network Parameters
n_input = 172 
n_classes = 1 
dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units
learning_rate = 0.005


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,128,256,3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)






# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1, channels=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, channels], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')


# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
  with tf.name_scope("Conv_net"):


      # Convolution Layer

      conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'],1,1)

      # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
      conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

      # Convolution Layer
      conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
      # Max Pooling (down-sampling)

      conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)


      fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
      fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
      fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
      # Apply Dropout
      fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

      # Output, class prediction
      out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])

      return out






# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 32]),name="w1"),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]),name="wc2"),
  #  'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 64]),name="wc3"),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32*64*64, 1024]),name="wd1"),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]),name="w_out")
}
tf.summary.histogram('weights1',weights['wc1'])
tf.summary.histogram('wc2',weights['wc2'])
#tf.summary.histogram('wc3',weights['wc3'])
tf.summary.histogram('wd1',weights['wd1'])
tf.summary.histogram('wout',weights['out'])


biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]),name="bc1"),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]),name="bc2"),
 #   'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]),name="bc3"),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]),name="bd1"),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]),name="b_out")
}
tf.summary.histogram('bc1',biases['bc1'])
tf.summary.histogram('bc2',biases['bc2'])
#tf.summary.histogram('bc3',biases['bc3'])
tf.summary.histogram('bd1',biases['bd1'])
tf.summary.histogram('bout',biases['out'])



# Construct model
with tf.name_scope("Predictions"):
  pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)
  tf.summary.histogram('predic',pred)


def tmp():
  with tf.name_scope("Cost"):
    t_pred = pred
    tf.summary.histogram('predictions',t_pred)
    tf.summary.histogram('labels',y)
    my_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss([t_pred,y])
    tf.summary.scalar('myloss',my_loss)
    softmax = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=t_pred, labels=y)
    tf.summary.histogram('softmax',softmax)
    sumloss = tf.contrib.slim.losses.mean_squared_error(t_pred,y)
    tf.summary.scalar('sumloss',sumloss)
    costt = tf.reduce_mean(softmax)

    return sumloss #costt

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tmp()#tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
tf.summary.scalar('cost',cost)
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)



# Evaluate model
correct_pred =  tf.less_equal( tf.abs(tf.subtract(pred,y)) ,10)  #tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar('accuracyyy',accuracy)


#init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()


with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorboard/log8")
  writer.add_graph(sess.graph)


  for epoch in range(1,200):
    print("start epoch:",epoch)

    imb_batch,label_batch = sess.run([imb_batch1,label_batch1])

    label_batch = label_batch.reshape(-1,1) 

    if epoch % 3 ==0:
      suma,_ =sess.run([merged,optimizer], feed_dict={x:imb_batch ,
       y:label_batch ,keep_prob: dropout})
      writer.add_summary(suma,epoch) 

    else:
      sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:imb_batch ,
       y:label_batch ,keep_prob: dropout})


  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Edit:

A typical image would look like the one below. I then want the model to tell me how much of the image (only counting the bars) the blue bars make up, in percentage. So I give as input images like this and the correct value (around 40% in this case).

I will later want to extend the model to tell me things like, how much more blue is it on the first line than the second, etc. I also want the model to be able to handle different numbers of "lines".

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRO1n.png)

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal exactly. You want to recognize an object, and the percentage is the confidence??? In general to recognize something you must train the model with some positives and some negatives examples. So normally you need at least two different classes. Could you provide some example of your training set and what is the prediction that you want?

Comment: Probably just replacing last layer and the cost is not enough. Try replacing last two-three layers. I am assuming you have used either `mean_absolute_error` or `mean_squared_error` as the loss function. I think `mae` will be better. If you use `mse`, make sure you keep the learning rate low enough. Keep an eye on your loss, if it starts giving you very high values: 1. decrease the learning rate 2. use some adaptive optimizer like `adam` or `rmsprop` or `adamax` etc.

Comment: @DavideBiraghi I edited the question, so hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes I used mse as loss function, and have tried learning rates as low as 0.0001. My loss is through the roof, I think there's is some big mistake I am making. 
I am thinking that I should add something as final layer which makes "regression". Now I have a fully connected layer as final layer, and use the output from that one as my prediction.

Comment: Why simply do you not count how many pixels have the specific color? Alternatively maybe you could trained the model with different images with different percentage of blue (each interval of percentage in a different class). In this case you have to teach to the model to recognize only the color percentage, so, for each class, you need the most general dataset possible.